# How can I manipulate each instance of all specific string values within an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

For each instance of a specific string, I want to return a new array. Let's suppose I have an array of strings like the following.

```
let stringArr = ["when", "the", "like", "because", "the", "apple" "like", "the", "star"]
```

What I end up with is a new array for each str, that includes the string that comes after every instance of that string. For example:

```
var whenArray = ["the"]

var theArray = ["like", "apple"]

var likeArray = ["because", "the"]

var becauseArray = ["the"]

var appleArray = ["like"]

var starArray = []
```

After each instance of the string `the`, we see the string `like` and `apple`.
After each instance of the string `like`, we see `like` and `the`.

Comment: do you have a problem statement? what does not work? please add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let strArr = ["when", "the", "like", "because", "the", "apple", "like", "the", "star"];

function nextArrs(strArr) {
    return strArr.reduce((acc, curr, idx, arr) => {
        let arrName = curr + 'Array';
        if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(arrName)) {
            acc[arrName] = [];
        }
        if (arr[idx + 1] !== undefined) {
            acc[arrName].push(arr[idx + 1]);
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
}

console.log(nextArrs(strArr));
```

Comment: I love this solution. I am simply going to take notes. I hope that soon, I'd be able to come up with solutions as soon as you did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
let strings = ["when", "the", "like", "because", "the", "apple", "like", "the", "star"];


const output = {};

for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  if (!output[strings[i]]) {
    output[strings[i]] = [];
  }

  if (i + 1 < strings.length) {
    output[strings[i]].push(strings[i + 1]); 
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Amazing solution and you figured it out fast too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let stringArr = ["when", "the", "like", "because", "the", "apple", "like", "the", "star"];

function findNextElementArray(arr){

  return arr.map(function(query, i){ 
    return {[query]: stringArr.map(function(item, index){
                  return (item === query ? (stringArr[index+1] ? stringArr[index+1]: false): false);
             }).filter(function(item){ return item !== false })
     }
  });
}


console.log(findNextElementArray(stringArr));
```